# Spring: service component return null in controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am new at spring and hibernate and i tried to create a project. I have researched and applied some techniques but i coulnt solve a problem. When I tried to access a service component in a controller, it returns null. Will it be about my missing configuration in spring? Please help me to solve the problem... thanks in advance..

UserController file:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String loginChk(ModelMap model, WebRequest req) {

        User u = userService.getByEmailPwd(email, pwd);
       /* ........ */       

        return "login";

    }
}


@Service("userService")    
public class UserServiceImp extends GenericManagerImp<User> implements  UserService 
{

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImp(UserDao userDao) {
        super(userDao);
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    public User getByEmailPwd(String email, String pwd) {

        return userDao.getByEmailPwd(email, pwd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add @Autowired over the property.

Comment: IT worked thank you very very veryyy mcuh i was goingto be crazy :)

Comment: I have added this commant as Answer feel free to upvote or accept thsi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@Autowired` over the property

Comment: Can you add the whole stacktrace to your question please?

Comment: Unfortunatelly i counld not beacuse of my status on stackoverflow.com I am a new user so I count send eevrthing :(

Comment: sory to send the stacktrace by this way

Comment: You have to add a default constructor to your bean. `public UserServiceImp(){}`

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.article.dao.GenericDaoImp.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: these last ones are all new in stakestrace

Comment: The org.hibernate.SessionFactory is missing.

Comment: @Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImp extends GenericDaoImp<User> implements UserDao {

 public UserDaoImp() {
  super(User.class);
 }

}

Comment: i meen the part befor "sory to send the stacktrace by this way"

Comment: public class GenericDaoImp<T> implements GenericDao<T> {

 private Class<T> persistentClass;

 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 public GenericDaoImp(final Class<T> persistentClass) {
  this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
  this.sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
 }

 public GenericDaoImp(final Class<T> persistentClass, SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
  this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
  this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
 }

 public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
  return this.sessionFactory;
 }

Comment: sessionFactory is in genericdao file

Comment: look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html) how to configure the SessionFactory in spring.

Comment: sorrry ok i will delete

Comment: In dao yes. But not in the applicationContext I think.